# Como acessar uma posição específica da memória RAM pelo endereço?

Tags: c, c++, ponteiro

Estou começando a estudar ponteiros em C/C++ e foi algo que me chamou bastante atenção pela robustez e a gama de possibilidades. Entretanto, só consigo acessar posições de memória atribuindo ao meu ponteiro um endereço de uma variável já alocada, como em:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){
    int x =0, *p =&x;
    printf("%x",p); 

    return 0;
}
```

E o endereço do meu ponteiro (como também o endereço das minhas variáveis), neste caso, é escolhido pelo Loader do sistema operacional, penso eu.

Eu gostaria de alocar minhas variáveis em posições específicas da memória (escolhidas por mim), e também gostaria de, por exemplo, acessar a posição 0x000001 da minha memória RAM (Sim! Eu quero ferrar o Sistema Operacional). Isto é possível utilizando ponteiros? Existe alguma outra forma de fazer isto? Qual e como?

Comment: Creio que só seja possível armazenar no heap não é? Ou terei uma violação de memória. Mas eu realmente gostaria de saber como fazer isto.

Comment: Acabei por aceitar a resposta do @GuilhermeB por ser mais completa e explicar o que ocorre "nos bastidores" que impossibilita de alocar um ponteiro em uma região específica da RAM. Também me forneceu detalhes bastante úteis e me explicou como utilizar um módulo de kernel para que de fato eu aloque o ponteiro onde quiser.

Comment: Agradeço a contribuição de todos, as duas respostas foram muito boas, utilizarei o código do @GuilhermeA em minhas aplicações embarcadas e isso vai me ajudar muito.

Obrigado a todos pela contribuição.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A começar, estritamente falando, você só pode escrever e ler dados de ponteiros válidos, ou seja, ponteiros criados a partir de objetos dentro de suas vidas. Um ponteiro para qualquer outro lugar é inválido e não pode ser lido ou escrito, embora possa existir (como o `NULL`). Mas, é claro, você está falando da realidade e da prática, e não de como deveria ser o mundo perfeito.

Em qualquer sistema operacional moderno existe algo chamado de memória virtual (*Virtual Memory*). Dessa forma cada processo existe e trabalha apenas com sua visão limitada da memória. Um processo vê a memoria como um grande bloco de 16 exbibytes (estou considerando 64-bit) na qual ele tem acesso a qualquer lugar. A cada endereço que ele tentar ler, o sistema traduzirá o endereço que o processo vê para o endereço em que os dados realmente estão. Assim dois processo diferentes podem ler exatamente o mesmo endereço e receber dados diferentes.

Essa memória virtual é dividida em páginas (geralmente blocos de 4 kibibytes) e o sistema tem uma tabela que atribui páginas virtuais a páginas reais. É isso que permite ao sistema, por exemplo, salvar uma página não muito usada no disco para liberar memória e recuperar ela assim que o processo tentar ler seu endereço, tudo de forma transparente.

Quando você tenta acessar um endereço que não está atribuído na tabela de páginas virtuais (ou quando tenta escrever em uma página somente leitura, ou executar uma não executável, etc) você terá uma **violação de memória**. Seu processo receberá um **SIGSEGV** e será finalizado. Um crash.

Por mais que você queira, não será possível causar qualquer dano no seu sistema usando apenas um ordinário processo. Você não pode ler a memória do kernel nem ler a memória de outros processos simplesmente usando ponteiros assim. Tudo que conseguirá é ler uma página que não existe e o processo morrerá.

Agora... Se você realmente quer causar problemas, então tem que fazer seu código ser executado como um pouco mais que um processo. Que tal um módulo de kernel? Nesse caso você é o próprio sistema e usa memória real, você está em ring-0. Nessa situação você pode ler ou escrever o que bem entender. Mas note que tentar ler um endereço fora da memória, por exemplo, te causará uma exceção de hardware. Uma bela tela azul ou um kernel panic para você.

Você pode também por seu código em um microcontrolador ou algo similar, executando sem a existência de um sistema operacional.

Comment: Muito interessante. Então, seu eu utilizar um módulo de kernel eu posso ter acesso direto a memória? Eu preciso dar permissões ou fazer algo do tipo? De que forma eu faria isto?

Comment: @Avelino Pode sim. Se tratando do Linux, você compila o código e o instala como módulo do kernel (precisa ser SU). Aqui tem um bom guia: [The Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/index.html).

Answer (score 6):

Como já apontado, você não pode dizer explicitamente onde uma variável será armazenada na memória, até porque muitas são as coisas feitas pelo sistema operacional com relação à memória em si (o que resulta no fato do mapeamento da memória virtual não ser um processo fixo).

Contudo, nada te impede de inicializar um ponteiro com um endereço de memória específico:

```
volatile unsigned int *ponteiro = (volatile unsigned int *)0x000001;
/* volatile está sendo usado com o intuito de garantir que o valor passado ao ponteiro não
   seja uma cópia previamente possuída pelo programa, ou seja, garante que seu valor está
   sendo obtido diretamente da memória em cada acesso. */
```

Comment: Neste caso, se o endereço for um endereço válido, ele será alocado sem problemas neste endereço? Posso fazer isto com variáveis também ou só com ponteiros? 

Eu trabalho com microcontroladores, sei que em Assembly é possível fazer isto tranquilamente. Mas eu nunca fiz em C e essa possibilidade me atraí muito. Grato por sua resposta.

Comment: Nesse caso precisa ser necessariamente um ponteiro pois você está o inicializando com um endereço de memória específico (fazendo com que ele aponte para aquele lugar). Se for um endereço de memória válido ele conseguirá apontar para lá, mas se você tentar fazer com que uma variável seja alocada em um endereço de memória fixo, por exemplo, aí o sistema pode tanto aceitar quanto rejeitar, sendo que a rejeição acontece se uma página que contém aquele endereço já tiver sido mapeada.